# EditText behavior for arabic locale

Tags: android, android-edittext, arabic

I have a login screen that consists of two EditText views. [image] When using an arabic locale the password input field gets right aligned and starting to work according to RTL language rules. [image] The username input field is not affected in any way. The layout XML for my two input fields looks like this:

```
<!-- Username input. -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_edittext_username_input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.66667dp"
    android:background="@drawable/general_inputfield_normal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="@string/login_input_username_hint"
    android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_hint" />

<!-- Password input. -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_edittext_password_input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.66667dp"
    android:background="@drawable/general_inputfield_normal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="@string/login_input_password_hint"
    android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_hint" />
```

I've tried to align the two and found out that `android:inputType="textPassword"` is the cause. Is there a way to make the password input field behave like the username input field, i.e. left aligned and left-to-right input, but still with the textPassword capabilities?

Comment: Note: running the app on a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1.1

Comment: You've used pre Edittext for the username and a custom EditText for the password..com.hm.widget.TrueTypeEditText, so it is not because of textPassword it is because of custom view

Comment: Sorry about that. :) It's got nothing to do with the custom EditText. First thing I did was to test with the android.widget.EditText instead, and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

using this it will be help you

```
  android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

```
android:gravity="start" 
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer, just a piece of code wont help much.

Answer (score -2):

try with     android:gravity="right" alignments , hope this helps